# How do I write the data for this JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I was trying to use an online fake data generator to generate sample data from my json schema but it did not accept my schema for some reason but I don't see anything wrong with it. I want to do it manually but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. Does the data below match the schema?

Schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://somesite.com",
  "description": "mychema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Form": {
      "description": "form properties",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "formproperty": {
          "description": "test value",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "FormElements": {
      "description": "form elements and their properties",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "title": "Form Element",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "description": "The unique identifier",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "positionX": {
            "description": "The X coordinate",
            "type": "number"
          },
          "positionY": {
            "description": "The Y coordinate",
            "type": "number"
          },
          "elementSpecificProperties": {
            "description": "unique properties",
            "type": "object",
            "oneOf": [
              { "$ref": "#/definitions/Label" }
            ]
          }
        }
      }

    }
  },

        "definitions": {
          "Label": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "value": {
              "description": "",
              "type": "string"

            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Data

```
{
    "Form":{
        "formproperty": "test"
    },
    "FormElements":[
        {
            "id": "1",
            "positionX":  20,
            "positionY":  15,

            "value": "testing1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "positionX":  5,
            "positionY":  12,

            "value": "testing2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that your schema is valid and that the data is valid against the schema.  However, based on your schema, I think what you meant is this.

```
{
  "Form": {
    "formproperty": "test"
  },
  "FormElements": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "positionX": 20,
      "positionY": 15,
      "elementSpecificProperties": {
        "value": "testing1"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "positionX": 5,
      "positionY": 12,
      "elementSpecificProperties": {
        "value": "testing2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```